# how to store data come from server to database in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
function storeData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.json-generator.com/j/bKQdCWJSKW?indent=4",
        type: "GET",
        accepts: "utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "test", 1000000);
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SEARCHRESULT (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY    AUTOINCREMENT,  data1,data2)');
                $.each(data.employe, function (ind, values) {
                    navigator.notification.alert("successful" + [values.firstName]);
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SEARCHRESULT (data1,data2) VALUES (?,?);', [values.firstName], [values.lastName]);
                });
            }, errorResult, successResultStoreData);
        }
    });
}
```

In above example I get data from server which is multiple records I get data properly but I am not able to store in a database. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: shouldn't statement be like `tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SEARCHRESULT (data1,data2) VALUES (?,?);', [values.firstName, values.lastName]);`?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: glad it worked. added as answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter values should be provided in an array, as

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SEARCHRESULT (data1,data2) VALUES (?,?);', 
              [values.firstName, values.lastName]);
```

regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the whole object in local storage.

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

The only time this wouldn't work is if you needed to query it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using directly

`tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SEARCHRESULT (data1,data2 ) VALUES ("' + values.firstName + '","' + values.lastName + '")');`